# Input validaton with a function call jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the correct jquery plugin to validate a few input elements on my page. I would like to be able to have the validation happen on the fly and if any of the validations fail it will call a function. I have been researching this and I can not find a good example on how to do this or what plugin to use. I ultimately just want to validate a few input fields such as first name, last name, email, phone, etc. and if any of them fail the Submit button is disabled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -- looks like it does what you want.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/